# Arithmetic series relationship with difference of two consecutive cubes. Is this a thing?

Tags: arithmetic, proof-verification

Excuse my dodgy notation and my write-up in general, this is the first proof I've done since leaving school a while back. Anywho, has anyone come across anything like this before? Read the whole thing, not just the arithmetic series stuff.

The sum of an ascending series, where *a* is the first integer, *k* is the common difference, and there are *n* terms.

$a+(a+k)+(a+2k)+⋯(a+(n-1)k)$
$$=na+[0+(n-1)k)+[1+(n-2)k]+[2+(n-3)k]+⋯$$
$$=na+\frac {n}{2}(n-1)k$$
$$=n\left[a+\frac{(n-1)k}{2}\right]$$

Difference between two consecutive cubes:
$2^3-1^3=7=(1×6)+1$
$3^3-2^3=19=(1+2)×6+1$
$4^3-3^3=37=(1+2+3)×6+1$

By observation, the difference between two consecutive cubes is equal to six times the sum of all integers between $0$ and the larger cubed integer, plus $1$.

Algebraically:
$$1+6\sum_{i=1}^x a_i=1+6{n\left[a+\frac{(n-1)k}{2}\right]}$$
Where $1$ is the first term and the common difference, and there are *x* terms.
$$=1+6{x\left[1+\frac{(x-1)}{2}\right]}$$

$$=1+6x+3x^2-3x$$

$$=3x^2+3x+1$$

$$=x^3+3x^2+3x+1-x^3$$

$$=(x+1)^3-x^3$$

Q.E.D

P.S. I always wanted to use Q.E.D but don't normally get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can prove it directly :
$$(n+1)^3 - n^3 = 3 n^2 + 3 n + 1 = 3 n (n + 1) + 1 = 6 \frac{n (n + 1)}  2 + 1  $$
$\frac{n (n + 1)}  2$ being the sum of all integers from $1$ to $n$

Comment: Thanks Claude, I was just wondering if this had, for want of a better word, noticed before?

Comment: @NickJanes. I suppose that people involved in integers noticed this but I am not among these. But, in any manner, it is an interesting remark. It would be interesting to see what happens with higher powers.