# Define recursively the sequence of the cubes of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $n $ be an element of the natural numbers, and let $s(n) $ be the series defined by the squares of the natural numbers, i.e. $s(n) =0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36,... $

I have worked out the recursive definition of this by noting the difference between each successive term is an odd number: $2n-1 $. By letting $f(0) = 0, f(1)=1 $, and $f(n) = f(n-1) + 2n-1 $. This works, since $f(0)=0, f(1)=f(0)+2(1)-1, f(2)=f(1)+2(2)-1$, etc.

Is there a way to do this with the set of cubes of the natural numbers, i.e $0,1,8,27,64,125,216,343,...$?
I noticed that the difference between $s(1)$ and $s(0)$ is 1, between $s(2)$ and $s(1)$ is $7$, between $s(3)$ and $s(2)$ is $19$, $s(4)$ and $s(3)$ is 37, etc. There's nothing really to go on there except that they seem to be primes. Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: They are increasing by $6,12,18,24,\dots$

Comment: No, they're not all primes.  Hint: differences of differences of differences.

Comment: Consider the similarity between $(n+1)^2 - n^2$ in the case of squares and $(n+1)^3 - n^3$ in the case of cubes.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/570131/139123 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/786977/139123

Comment: $(n+1)^3-n^3$ is prime for $n\in \{1,2,3,4,6\}.$ But $6^3-5^3=91=(7)(13)$ and $8^3-7^3=169=13^2.$ There are a lot of small primes. $48$% of the  odd numbers from $1$ to $99$  are prime.  Small numerical values of  a sequence often produce primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(n)=n^3$. Then
\begin{align}
f(n+1)=(n+1)^3=n^3+3n^2+3n+1=f(n)+3n^2+3n+1
\end{align}

Comment: You need to also define $f(0)=0$ otherwise $ f(n)$ could be $n^3+k$ for some positive constant $k.$